# Best links architecture for items under sections and categories?

Tags: seo, links, architecture

Let's imagine a website with items organized by sections and categories, with those examples values:

**Sections** (articles, threads, events, directory)

```
http://www.domain.com/section-name/
```

Display all items (title, date, description, author, main pic) of this section and all categories.

**Categories** (animals, arts, movies, sciences...)

```
http://www.domain.com/section-name/category-name/
```

Display all items (title, date, description, author, main pic) of this section and this category.

**Item page**

Display an item data: title, date, description, content, pictures, author.

What is the better link to those pages for users and SEO?

```
1 - http://www.domain.com/section-name/category-name/item-title_id.html    
or    
2 - http://www.domain.com/item-title_id.html
```

The first solution seems logical for users and crawlers bot. But is there a maximum length of url for a good SEO?

The second solution is lighter for SEO and users, but doesn't explain what is this page.